# BDD script for performance of text showing up on summary pane as I type

Tags: testing, bdd, requirements

I want to write a BDD for performance requirements but am not too sure how to separate out the UI details from the requirement itself in this case. I have got a summary plane in my application where text that I enter in my main form as I type appears in the summary plane. The requirement I wrote is below:

```
Given as a User
When I fill in "Bob" as "Customer Name"
Then "Bob" appears as "Customer Name" in the summary plane
```

I got two questions. Is this advisable and how would I add details that the name "Bob" should appear in the summary plane as I type and not appear later ?

Comment: What do you mean by "later"? You should see "Bob" as you are typing, and "Bob" should not become visible only when you are finished typing?

Comment: I should see Bob as I type.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this. You could spawn another thread that does the typing and the test thread checks the auto complete for the given text. The other way would be to type each letter individually and check after each character to see if the expected text shows up.

I think the easiest way is to check after each character has been typed. As long as you see the expected text at least once in between typing each character, then the step passes.